# How to call a function when QDialog Cancel or OK is pressed?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qdialog

I am doing 3 tabs from `QDialog`. Then adding 2 widget and 1 QDialog to 3 tabs.
I have called the `QDialog::accept` and `QDialog::reject`. But I want custom methods to be called and on calling them should reset the dialog screen to list box selected screen. My code follows:

```
BTSettingsTab::BTSettingsTab(const QFileInfo &fileInfo, QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
...........
.............
QLabel *topLabel = new QLabel(tr("Choose setting :"));

    QListWidget *settingsListBox = new QListWidget;
    QStringList settings;

    /*for (int i = 1; i <= 30; ++i)
        applications.append(tr("Application %1").arg(i));
    applicationsListBox->insertItems(0, applications);*/

    settings.append(tr("newConfiguration:"));
    settings.append(tr("Edit Configuration:"));
    settings.append(tr("Delete Configuration:"));
    settings.append(tr("add current location to  turnoff Places:"));
    settings.append(tr("temporarily turnoff distance:"));
    settings.append(tr("temporarily turn off turnoff places:"));
    settings.append(tr("factory reset:"));
    settings.append(tr("turn on distance:"));
    settings.append(tr("turn on turnoff places:"));
    settings.append(tr("exit"));
    settingsListBox->insertItems(0,settings);
QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok
                                             | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

            connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, this, &QDialog::accept);
            connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, this, &QDialog::reject);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(topLabel);
    layout->addWidget(settingsListBox);
layout->addWidget(buttonBox);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

I saw your post. Thanks. I impleted the overloaded functions and breakpoint hits them. I got the row number of selected item.I used  QString * curr = settingsListBox->currentItem()->text();

Now how do I start a new window?

Comment: If you have a second question, you should [ask it as a separate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which). Hint: how do you start *this* window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods `QDialog::accept` and `QDialog::reject` are virtual, so they can be overriden in your custom dialog (in your case - `BTSettingsTab` which inherits from `QDialog`).

If you want to *substitute* behavior on `accept` and `reject` - just implement your desired behavior in the overriden methods. Or you can implement your own methods `BTSettingsTab::_OnAccept()` and `_OnReject()` and connect buttons to them instead of connecting them to `QDialog::accept` and `reject`.

If you want to *add* your custom behavior to default `QDialog`'s behavior - call `QDialog::accept()` and `QDialog::reject` respectively in the end of the overloaded versions.